# iOS app expected behavior after the user removes the previously added authorization from the Facebook app?

Tags: ios, facebook, authorization

I'm successfully posting to Facebook from our Unity iOS game by initializing at game launch then posting message by first checking the session validity and triggering the login if needed.

At first call, I authorize the game from the Facebook app.
Trying to start the process again, I go to the Facebook app prefs and delete the app authorization.

Now when I try to post again from the game, the post message completion handler has no errors but the post does not appear on the user's wall.

What is the process to correct this? Is there a way to check that the game is authorized before posting, and ask for a new authorization if it's not?
Or is the user decision final and they need to reinstall the app to reset everything?

Even though I'm using Prime31's Facebook plugin for Unity, I'm interested in an iOS SDK answer to this question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an exception, that you need to handle.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"didFailWithError : %@",[error description]);

    NSDictionary* userinfo=[error userInfo];
    NSString *type=[[userinfo valueForKey:@"error"]valueForKey:@"type"];
    if([type isEqualToString:@"OAuthException"]){
        NSLog(@"Exception from oauth let's take new token");
        [facebook authorize:_permissions delegate:self];
    }

}
```

Use this delegate function to handle exception.